# Refused to execute script from '.../bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have an application with React/webpack frontend and Django/python backend.  It has deployed successfully to heroku in the past.  It has been sometime since I did anything in the application and after some recent updates I wanted to update the deployed version.  Heroku reports that the application deployed successfully but when I try to access it, I get the error:

Refused to execute script from 'https://pairshead-2020.herokuapp.com/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      { test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      { test: /\.woff2?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: 'src',
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: 8000,
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:4000'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    })
  ]
}
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "results",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "serve:backend": "python manage.py runserver 4000",
    "serve:frontend": "webpack-dev-server",
    "seed": "python manage.py loaddata results/fixtures.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "bulma": "^0.7.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-image": "^2.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.0.4",
    "react-select-async-paginate": "^0.3.13",
    "react-toastify": "^5.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.11.1",
    "python": "3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
# import dj_database_url
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import django_heroku
load_dotenv()
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/


SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', 'pairshead-results.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'results',
    'django_filters',
    'computed_property',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 25,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'PAGE_SIZE_QUERY_PARAM': 'page_size',
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
    ],
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())
# DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
```

urls.py (from projects folder)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('django-admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/', include('results.urls')),
    path('api/', include('jwt_auth.urls')),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
]
```

wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for project project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import clubs
from .views import events
from .views import bands
from .views import crews
from .views import competitors
from .views import times
from .views import results
from .views import masters_adjustments
from .views import original_event_category


urlpatterns = [
path('clubs/', clubs.ClubListView.as_view()),
path('club-data-import/', clubs.ClubDataImport.as_view()),
path('events/', events.EventListView.as_view()),
path('event-data-import/', events.EventDataImport.as_view()),
path('band-data-import/', bands.BandDataImport.as_view()),
path('bands/', bands.BandListView.as_view()),
path('crews/', crews.CrewListView.as_view(), name='crews-list'),
path('crews/<int:pk>', crews.CrewDetailView.as_view(), name='crews-detail'),
path('', crews.CrewListView.as_view()),
path('results/', results.ResultsListView.as_view()),
path('results-export/', results.ResultDataExport.as_view()),
path('crew-update-rankings/', crews.CrewUpdateRankings.as_view()),
path('crew-data-import/', crews.CrewDataImport.as_view()),
path('crew-data-export/', crews.CrewDataExport.as_view()),
path('competitor-data-export/', competitors.CompetitorDataExport.as_view()),
path('competitor-data-import/', competitors.CompetitorDataImport.as_view()),
path('race-times/', times.RaceTimeListView.as_view()),
path('race-times/<int:pk>', times.RaceTimeDetailView.as_view()),
path('crew-race-times/', times.CrewRaceTimesImport.as_view()),
path('masters-adjustments-import/', masters_adjustments.MastersAdjustmentsImport.as_view()),
path('original-event-import/', original_event_category.OriginalEventCategoryImport.as_view()),
]
```

I have a views folder with 9 view files:
**init**.py

```
from .bands import *
from .clubs import *
from .competitors import *
from .crews import *
from .events import *
from .times import *
from .results import *
from .masters_adjustments import *
```

procfile

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

Very grateful for any help anyone can offer.  After reading a few similar questions, I tried setting {output: publicPath: '/'} and {historyApiFallback: true} in webpack.config.js but didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 6):

Your webpack and package.json configurations are absolutely fine. Your particular MIME type ("text/html") problem is in your Django configuration.

1. The views.py in your React frontend needs a `content_type` argument in the HttpResponse.
2. Heroku needs to know where your Webpack build files are.

You've configured Webpack to compile a production build of your React app, named this 'bundle.js', and told Webpack to put it in a folder called 'frontend/dist' along with a production build of your index.html. In Django parlance, these are your "static" files. (If you were using create-react-app instead of Webpack, this is the stuff in the 'build' folder.) In your settings.py, you need to tell heroku where to find these 'static' files.  (explained below).  But first, fix your frontend/views.py.

Your `Home(View)` is telling Heroku (or any server) to respond by sending index.html. Your Webpack 'HTMLWebpackPlugin' has injected a script into index.html which asks your `Assets(View)` to: look for bundle.js (and any other files stored in the same folder on the server), open it as 'rb', (which stands for 'read binary'), and return it to the user as an HttpResponse.

Your "refused to execute script ... MIME type ('text/html')" problem stems from Django's default `content_type` setting for an HttpResponse, which is `text/html`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#id3

Fix this by including a `content_type='application/javascript'` argument in the return statement of `Assets(View)` like so:

```
class Assets(View):

    def get(self, _request, filename):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dist', filename)

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            with open(path, 'rb') as file:
                return HttpResponse(file.read(), content_type='application/javascript')
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

With that sorted, there are several changes you need to make to your settings.py file help Heroku's Django configuration serve those files correctly.

As an aside, Heroku's Django deployment process recommends installing a middleware package ("Whitenoise") to compress and manage your static files, and a wsgi interface ("Gunicorn") to help Heroku communicate with Django. Your lack of these is not causing your issue, but they are part of Heroku's current recommended configuration so I am including them below.

First, in your settings.py your need to include the address of your heroku app in your allowed hosts, as well as your port and localhost like so:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your-app-name.herokuapp.com/', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

Then you need to add the whitenoise middleware (don't forget to pip install it.) Make sure you list it second, directly after the django's security middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
...
```

Then you need to add the path to where Webpack is storing your assets to the DIRS, in your case frontend/dist:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/dist')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
     ...
```

And finally and most importantly, you need to configure where you are storing your static files.  In your case:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 
"whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/dist')
]
```

The reason there is both a setting for STATIC_ROOT and for STATICFILES_DIRS is that STATIC_ROOT is where all the static files will be collected when Heroku automatically calls the command: `manage.py collectstatic` during deployment.

STATICFILES_DIRS is used to include additional directories collectstatic needs to look for. Make sure you reference the path to the folder where Webpack is storing your build files correctly!  For your particular directory setup, that should be 'frontend/dist'

Don't forget to change your DEBUG settings to False for deployment.

Finally, you need to pip install gunicorn and change your Procfile to look like this:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn project.wsgi --preload --log-file -
```

You should really check out the Heroku link: https://blog.heroku.com/from-project-to-productionized-python because it walks you through Heroku and Heroku's environment setup. It also states Heroku expects a requirements.txt file specifying the versions of the python packages you have installed and a runtime.txt file specifying your version of Django. But but since you're using Pipenv instead of venv, I think your Pipfile makes those unnecessary.

Here is a outline following Heroku's from-product-to-productionized  instructions for a Django deployment to Heroku, with the necessary steps for including a React + Webpack frontend inserted in the proper order:
--------Pre-deployment-------------

1. Signup for [Heroku](https://signup.heroku.com)
2. Install the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install)
3. Set up a virtual enviroment with either `pipenv shell` or or venv  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html
4. Update .gitignore to include:

```
/your-venv-directory      
__pycache__
db.sqlite3         
your-app-name/static/
frontend/dist
.env
```

5. [Heroku recommends you use your settings.py for local development and a create a second file (heroku.py) with the package django-environ to import your env settings for deployment. It's much easier their way, but you are managing fine with your env config so I'll skip that here. Check [modularize-your-settings](https://blog.heroku.com/from-project-to-productionized-python#modularize-your-settings) and [setting-up-code-heroku-py](https://blog.heroku.com/from-project-to-productionized-python#setting-up-code-heroku-py-code) for the recommended setup]
6. Install `django-heroku` and add
   `import django_heroku`
   to the top of the settings.py file and
   `django_heroku.settings(locals())`
   to the bottom of the settings.py file
7. Install `whitenoise` and add it as middleware to settings.py
8. Install `psycopg2` http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/
   This is notoriously difficult to install, but installing the raw `psycopg2-binary` as you did here seems to work in a pinch.
9. Create a `requirements.txt` file and run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and create a `runtime.txt` file and specify your current python build version so things don't break down the road.  As you're using pipenv which generates a Pipfile.lock I'm not sure this is strictly necessary, as pipenv supercedes  but you should freeze your current package and python build versions into your Pipfile, so things don't break down the road.
10. Install the web servers gateway interface (WSGI) process that actually serves your heroku application: `gunicorn`
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn
    https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html
11. Create a file named `Procfile` (MAKE SURE THE 'P' IS CAPITALIZED!!!) and add:

```
    release: python manage.py migrate
    web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --preload --log-file -
```

12. Make sure you have a build script in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack -p" }
```

13. Run this build script (`yarn build`) and confirm your app is working locally.

--------Deployment------------------
From your terminal run:

1. `heroku login`
2. `heroku create --region=eu your-app-name`
3. `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs`
4. `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python`  (Make sure you add the buildpacks in that order!)
5. `heroku config:set ALLOWED_HOSTS=your-app-name.herokuapp.com`
6. `heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings` (if you added a deployment settings file to use django-environ as the modularize-your-settings link suggested above, then use `heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.herokuDotPyOrWhateverYouNamedIt`)
7. `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=INSERTASECURESECRETKEYPASSWORD`
8. `heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=1`
9. `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`
10. Make sure you are on your master branch and all changes have been committed to git and run
    `git push heroku master`
    or if you are working from another branch, commit to git and run
    `git push heroku yourbranch:master` replacing 'yourbranch' with the name of your branch.
11. `heroku run python manage.py migrate`
12. If you have a fixtures.json file containing your database seeds run
    heroku run python manage.py loaddata your-django-project-name/fixtures.json
13. `heroku ps:scale web=1`
14. `heroku open`
15. If there are any errors, run
    `heroku logs --tail`
    to investigate

Comment: Thanks so much mtcolvard - such a clear and comprehensive answer and, more importantly, it worked!!!  Amazing!!